# APK - There was a problem parsing the package

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, apk

So I am trying to install an .APK from a web page using ASP.NET. The below is my ASP code which works, it fetches the file and downloads onto the emulator and the android itself. However when I go to run the I get the parsing error.

```
        FileName = application.FileName;
        FileLocation = application.VersionLocation;
        FileExtension = application.FileExtension;
        FileNameWithExtension = application.FileName + application.FileExtension;

        string iUrl = Path.Combine(FileLocation, FileNameWithExtension);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
        string Header = "Attachment; Filename=" + FileNameWithExtension;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header);
        FileInfo Dfile = new FileInfo(iUrl);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(Dfile.FullName));
        Response.End();
```

I have googled it and googled it and they all suggested checking the API version which is 30. The emulator is also 30 and so is the Android itself. This is fine.

I have also allowed unknown apps to be installed on the emulator and android itself from google. Which is where I am downloading from. This is fine.

I have done a couple cold boots since, just in case. This is fine.

The one thing I just cannot understand and feel its the reason (not sure how or why) but the APK before download is 3.8mb and when its downloaded to the emulator or android itself, its 3.4mb. Dragging and dropping the original 3.8mb APK works fine but its the download thats breaking it.

I just cant figure it out and why its getting corrupt

Comment: Did you examine the downloaded file? A .apk is just a zipped file with a bunch of files inside it. Try changing the extension to .zip and opening both and comparing. If you can't open the one that you downloaded from your site that way, then perhaps it's getting corrupted somehow.

Comment: I suggest to use handler and not aspx page because its possible to get an extra gzip that breaks your file. - also add one more `Response.Flush();` before the End() ; and  also add  `Response.Buffer = false;` - also try the `Response.OutputStream.Write` and not the writefile - you must double check that the writefile is for binary and not only for text - I never use it.